# jQuery remove the prev occurance of a class?

Tags: jquery

I have a class that I want to dynamically remove based on a link.  How do I select the parent "added" class with jQuery.  There can be multibpule instances of the class I only want to remove the closest parent.

Example:

```
<div class="added">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        <label>Add Item<br />
            <span>What to Add</span>
        </label>
        <div class="rightbox">
            <% fields_for "items[related_items][]", add do |item_form|%>
                <%= item_form.text_field :add %>
            <%= link_to_function "remove", **"('div.added').empty()"** %>
            <% end %>       
        </div>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="added">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        <label>Add Item<br />
            <span>What to Add</span>
        </label>
        <div class="rightbox">
            <% fields_for "items[related_items][]", add do |item_form|%>
                <%= item_form.text_field :add %>
            <%= link_to_function "remove", **"('div.added').empty()"** %>
            <% end %>       
        </div>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="added">
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        <label>Add Item<br />
            <span>What to Add</span>
        </label>
        <div class="rightbox">
            <% fields_for "items[related_items][]", add do |item_form|%>
                <%= item_form.text_field :add %>
            <%= link_to_function "remove", **"('div.added').empty()"** %>
            <% end %>       
        </div>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want closest parent and the link is *inside* the relevant div then:

```
$("a.classname").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div.added").removeClass("added");
  return false;
});
```

I'm not certain that's relevant to what you're doing as I'm not familiar with ASP.NET but the above is the vanilla jQuery way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind just figured it out....  see below for anyone viewing this question.

```
$(this).closest('.added').empty()
```